# locally loaded css file is empty

Tags: html, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My HTML page starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../css/semantic-2.1.8.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/semantic-2.1.8.min.js">   </script>
....
```

This is running within CefSharp hosted within .Net
Within chrome-devtools when I select the Sources tab it lists the files. If I select the js files they show the correct content. If I select the css file it is empty.

The file on the disk exists and has the correct contents.
If I force a refresh using window.location.reload() the following message appears

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "local://wwwpub/css/semantic-2.1.8.min.css".
```

It remains blank though.

Comment: Try to interpret the css-file as a "text/css". Add to link tag type="text/css"

Comment: Assuming your using a `scheme handler` to serve `local://` make sure you return the correct mime type for the file.

Comment: Thanks Alex but it didn't work

Comment: @amaitland, Thank you very much that did it.